# Referencing a .NET library from Ruby - Possible?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails

Wondering if anyone has ever attempted this? Basically looking for the same functionality as PHPs DOTNET() function.

Comment: It's certainly possible on IronRuby. But on regular MRI? I guess there it's not that easy.